# Why does my custom Minecraft launcher not correctly start processes?

Tags: java, command-line, process, minecraft

Since my school computers blocks unknown apps or `.exe` files but have Java installed, I wrote my own launch system that I can use instead of the regular Minecraft launcher.

This works great. The launcher gives you a command to paste back into Powershell ISE (the only unblocked terminal) to start the game. However, I feel the non-tech-savvy people would have a hard time with this so I'm trying to make my program launch the game itself.

I'm using the following code:

```java
try {
    /*ProcessBuilder procbuilder = new ProcessBuilder(processArgs);
     procbuilder.inheritIO();
     procbuilder.start();*/
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).waitFor();
} catch (java.io.IOException | java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
     System.out.println("Exception while starting Minecraft: " + e);
}
```

My `command` variable is *always* a valid Java command that works when pasted into a terminal. I have a template file that my program reads from and replaces some placeholders (for directories, session-specific arguments and such).

I am able to use `exec()` to run other programs just fine. The following code works as expected:

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe abc.txt");
// or
Runtime.getRuntime.exec(new String[] {"notepad.exe", "abc.txt"});
```

I have passed my command and arguments the same way as demonstrated.

Why does this code cause Minecraft to not display a window of any kind? Using ProcessExplorer, I can see that the process was created and spun off but, as opposed to pasting the command in a terminal, never shows the game window or any sort of indication it's running. **Why does Java not run this correctly as opposed to entering the same command into a terminal?** FWIW, ProcessExplorer shows that the process I tried to start *does* have the correct arguments, but clearly something is different.

Per request, I have pasted the full command I'm trying to run.

```
java "-Dox.name=Windows 10" "-Dos.version=10.0" "-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\javaLibraries\" "-Dminecraft.launcher.brand=sidecraft" "-Dminecraft.launcher.version=2.3.592" "-Dminecraft.client.jar=C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\version\1.12.2.jar" -cp "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\com\mojang\patchy\1.3.9\patchy-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.4.0\jna-4.4.0.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.3\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.1.9.Final\netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\21.0\guava-21.0.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\commons-io-2.5.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.5.25\authlib-1.5.25.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\com\mojang\realms\1.10.22\realms-1.10.22.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\7.1.0\fastutil-7.1.0.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.8.1\log4j-api-2.8.1.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\log4j-core-2.8.1.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\libraries\com\mojang\text2speech\1.10.3\text2speech-1.10.3.jar;C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\version\1.12.2.jar" -Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\version\client-1.12.xml" net.minecraft.client.main.Main --version 1.12.2 --accessToken NO_TOKEN --gamedir C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2 --assetsDir C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\MC1-12-2\assets --assetIndex 1.12 --uuid 4290304c-2bb5-4f73-b5cc-1e545bd766a1 --userType msa --versionType release
```

Comment: What command is it exactly? Can you start other GUI programs like Notepad or Firefox?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I have added a link to the command. Other GUI programs work correctly.

Comment: @user14328040 "Error, this is a private paste or is pending moderation. If this paste belongs to you, please login to Pastebin to view it." Why can't you just edit the command directly into your question?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica When I created the question, pasting my command resulted in the code block taking up a full screen height of text but it appears to stay on one line now, probably due to a formatting error. Sorry about that. It's there, now. My paste also appears to be "Pending Moderation" for some reason.

Comment: When you tried with the overload that takes an array of strings, did you do it like `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(new String[] {"java", "-Dox.name=Windows 10", ...});` or like `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(new String[] {"java", "\"-Dox.name=Windows 10\"", ...});`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica It's being processed as `new String[] {"java", "\"-Dox.name=Windows 10\"", ...});` because of how it was reading from my configuration file. After removing the wrapping quotes from the lines in my configuration file it works! Thanks for your help, I'll answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading from my configuration file, some lines (and thus some arguments) had wrapping quotes. As such, they were being read into the arguments String array as `new String[] {"java", "\"-Dos.name=Windows 10\"", ...};`.

Removing the wrapping quotes from my arguments solved the issue, resulting in the arguments then being constructed as `new String[] {"java, "-Dos.name=Windows 10", ...}`.